# using Salesforce classic, how to bulk transfer ownership of contacts

Tags: batch

Contact owners are now inactive. I need to update ownership of about 1000 contacts. I use Salesforce Classic for my small non-profit.

Answer (score 0):

[Create a Report](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_builder_create.htm&type=5), [Export that Report as a CSV](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_export.htm&type=5), add/change a CSV column to set the owner, then use the Contacts tab and choose > [Import Accounts & Contacts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=importing.htm&type=5). Everything you need to know is in the documentation.

Comment: What fields would need to be in this report I download? When I import, will I be creating new users or overwrite only the fields I download? I am not tech familiar with "Anonymous execute" either. Why is this so difficult? I have to change 2500 contacts!!

Comment: @user83194 The CSV file just needs the Contact ID and Contact Owner or Contact Owner ID fields (just two fields). I don't necessarily advise you run "Execute Anonymous" unless you know a little bit of what you're doing. The import wizard is pretty simple, you just need a CSV file. Seriously, go ahead and give it a try, you might be surprised how easy it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Dataloader or [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/query.php) to export your data and replace the OwnerId. Both tools allow you to update your adjusted csv file as well.

Another way of doing this is to execute the below code snipped in Anonymous execute. Be carefull as incorrect OwnerId's could mess up your data!

```
    Id oldOwnerId = '<record id of inactive user>';
    Id newOwnerId = '<record id of replacing user>';

    List<Contact> contacts = [
      SELECT Id, OwnerId
      FROM Contact
      WHERE OwnerId = :oldOwnerId];

    for (Contact c :contacts) {
      c.OwnerId = newOwnerId;
    }

    update contacts;
```